# Convert an XML File Into an Embedded Resource

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, msbuild, mstest

I have an XML file in a MSTEST project.  It is an entity-framework Storage Specification Definition Language (SSDL) file.  I'd like to know what is the easiest way to have the mstest project automatically convert the SSDL file into an embedded resource, so that the "usual" entity framework connection string can reference it.

Ordinarily SSDL is automatically embedded as a resource.  However, this SSDL file is generated from a custom XSLT transform, which is why I need to have my own way to transform it into an embedded resource.

Answer (score 0):

http://cf-bill.blogspot.com/2007/11/c-use-embedded-resource.html will help you to create xml file as a embedded resource.